# How can I get real estate images wider than 18mm (on an entry level Nikon)?

Tags: wide-angle, lens-recommendation, real-estate

I have a Nikon D3300 with the standard 18-200 lens.

I need it to take internal house photos for real estate.  The current lens does not quite get enough in shot.  I don't want to spend too much on a new lens so can anyone suggest a better lens for the job or even a wide angle add-on to the current lens.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What to look for in a wide angle lens?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/48183/what-to-look-for-in-a-wide-angle-lens). Welcome to the site Matthew! Note that specific product recommendations are generally off topic here. We try to provide users the knowledge to make their own decisions on buying equipment vs point at specific models. The linked to answer I've provided should do exactly that. See my own answer on that question.

Answer (score 2):

Any lens with a minimum focal-length of 18 will be wider than your current one. While a high-quality one performs better and is more expensive, if you are taking photos to post on a real-estate site or anything but a large print, you do not necessarily need the best quality. You do not need it to be very bright either because one would expect to shoot stopped-down to get a good depth-of-field.

With that in mind, something like the Tokina 11-16mm F/2.8 will perform remarkably well. Nikon also has a 12-24mm F/4 which is quite good. For the ultimate rectilinear wide-angle, there is always the Sigma 8-16mm F/4.5-5.6, although at such wide-angle things can appear heavily distorted. You can use the [Lens Search](http://www.neocamera.com/search_lens.php) on my site to look for [Nikon F-mount ultra-wide-angle rectilinear lenses](http://www.neocamera.com/search_lens.php?mount=nikon&focalwide=12%3Amax&by=feature&rectilinear=1) which shows there are quite a few options around.

Answer (score 1):

The [Sigma 10-20 f4-5.6](http://www.photozone.de/nikon--nikkor-aps-c-lens-tests/308-sigma-af-10-20mm-f4-56-dc-ex-hsm-lab-test-report--review) is certainly worth looking at as well.

You said not *not quite* wide enough, so if you're simply looking for a bit more width, maybe a lens starting at 16mm might be a choice.  That 2mm difference from 18mm may seem small, but at wide angles every mm is noticeable.  Nikon do a 16-85mm.

I would also mention the possibility to build panoramas from multiple shots ( using software like [open source Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/).  This allows you the flexibility of a normal zoom lens in a standard range while having the option to make some wider images from two or three overlapping shots.  Not suitable for scenes with substantial movement, although you can sometimes manage to cope with a little movement.  Worth considering for some purposes at least.